# https.request doesn't work under callback in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, async.js

I am calling Google API using the `https` library. It works perfectly when it is invoked as a stand-alone function, but it doesn't work under `async.waterfall`.

I am sure I am doing something wrong. Where is the mistake? I don't see any error too. It just exits the program. Am I doing anything wrong with `async`?

Here is the snippet:

```js
 async.waterfall([
  (callback) => {
    console.log("In the first callback");

    const options = {
      host: 'www.googleapis.com',
      path: `/oauth2/v4/token?code=${authorizationCode}&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&grant_type=${grantType}`,
      port: 443,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    };

    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log("Inside Request - response came");
      console.log(`statusCode changed: ${res.statusCode}`);
      
      let geoData = [];
      res.on('data', (d) => {
        geoData.push(d);
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
        try {
          geoData = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(geoData).toString());
          console.log(geoData);

          const response = {
            statusCode: res.statusCode,
            body: JSON.stringify(geoData),
          };
        
          return callback(null, response);
        } catch (error) {
          return callback(error);
        }
      });
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      return callback(e.message);
    });

    req.end();

    console.log("End of first callback");
  }
], (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    }
    return result;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the asynchronous type of NodeJs, and with the way you have your function written, `req.end()` is executing before the response arrives. Move `req.end()` inside `req.on(...)` and `res.on()`. You only want to end the request after you receive a response or an error. Moreover, you should add `return callback()` inside `res.on('data')` in order to notify async that the function has finished executing